# Phoenix: Only allow subscription to one sub topic on a channel at a time

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

If a user has joined a topic, say `"rooms:lobby"` and then the user joins another sub topic on the same channel, like `"rooms:party"`. How can I force the user to be leave "rooms:lobby" from the backend. I have tried filtering the broadcast, but haven't had any luck. I would prefer to just terminate connection to old sub topics over filtering broadcasts.

```
defmodule MyApp.RoomsChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel
  intercept ["new_msg"]

  def join("rooms:" <> room_id, _params, socket) do
    {:ok, assign(socket, :room_id, room_id)
  end

  def handle_out("new_msg", payload, socket) do
    if current_room?(socket.assigns[:room_id], socket.topic) do
      push socket, "new_msg", payload
      {:noreply,socket}
    else
      {:noreply, socket}
    end
  end

  defp current_room?(room_id, "rooms:" <> sub_topic) do
    room_id == sub_topic
  end
end
```

I know it's possible to leave a topic from the front-end, but I need to ensure that only they current topic they are viewing gets the payload and not any of the previous topics that where subscribed to on a particular channel.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. Each topic is going to run in a different channel, in a different process. So given the code above, if you are on "rooms:1" and "rooms:3", they will be completely separated, even though they use the same logic. So if you want the user to leave, you can return `{:stop, :normal, :ok, :state}` or similar things from any event.

Comment: Let me give some more context. The app is being used to push notification that are sent via RPC from a rails app to a SPA built with react/flux. If this where a vanilla request/response REST app, changing routes would have the page reloaded and the socket connection renewed then join the sub topic with the correct id. I'm assuming at this point the old connections and topic subscription would be lost. I trying to achieve the same behaviour with a route change on a SPA.

Comment: I have kind of solved this with a `gen_server` that keeps track of the most recently joined sub topic, then in the `handle_out` I send a leave event telling the client to leave it is an old sub topic, instead of the original payload. This feels likes it's not the most appropriate way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like you are trying to join 1 channel per route, and you want to switch channels when the route changes instead of accumulating multiple channels. My guess is you are joining the channel inside of a lifecycle method (e.g. ComponentWillMount) from a high level React component.

If so, why not terminate the channel from the client in ComponentWillUnmount? This should fire just before your route changes on the client.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, by adding the `join` and `leave` inside the router transitions callbacks.